# Prove the limit of a piecewise function?

Tags: real-analysis

Question is in picture. For some reason this is totally boggling me, I have no idea how to apply the epsilon-delta definition to this. I feel a little lost approaching piecewise functions, I feel like I'm missing a crucial concept and I'd appreciate any help.

> Let $f(x)$ be the function whose domain is all $\mathbb R$ given by the rule
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 42 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb Z\\
> 0 & \text{if } x \notin \mathbb Z
> \end{cases}$$

Meant to prove that the limit is $0$. I'm pretty confused, does the limit even exist? It seems to me that the limit is $42$ if $x$ is approaching an integer and $0$ if $x$ is approaching any other real number.

Comment: You are confusing the value the function takes at $x_0$ and the limit to $x_0$. When you are taking a limit you don't care about the value the function takes there, it could even not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } 0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$$

As you can see, the value of $f$ at $x_0$ it's never taken into consideration. The point $x_0$ could be outside $f$'s dominion and the limit wouldn't change. What's important, instead, are the neighborhoods of $x_0$.

We want to prove that the limit is $0$ everywhere. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, we want to find $\delta$ such that
$$0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)| < \varepsilon$$
Can you do that? Hint: consider $\delta \in (\lfloor x_0\rfloor, \lfloor x_0\rfloor + 1)$.

Comment: I'm starting to see what you're saying but I'm struggling trying to algebraically connect what I pick delta to be to the implication that the absolute value of f(x) is less than any epsilon. Sorry if I'm being dense, for some reason I'm just not seeing this.

Comment: So what I've come up with now is this: if we pick delta to be between x0 and x0 + 1, it guarantees via properties of the inequality that x won't be equivalent to an integer, meaning that f(x) must return zero and thus will be smaller than any epsilon. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the above comment is right (but I'd appreciate being told if that's not the case) so I feel like I understand your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Bookie You're right, $\delta$ is chosen to avoid integers. No need to be sorry, props to you for trying to understand the concept completely instead. And you are doing the right thing, because the concept of limit is essential and foundamental in analysis. It's just a couple of inequalities but many big concepts and tools (derivatives, integrals to name a few) are built upon it.

Comment: I understand that comments like what I'm about to say aren't really what this site is geared toward, but I wanted to say thank you for saying that. I was beating myself up for not getting this for sure and reading your comment was very encouraging to me. I'll continue to press forward in analysis.

Comment: @Bookie Don't worry, everyone struggles with more abstract concepts at first. And this will continue as you continue your studies. You have to learn to be comfortable outside you thinking comfort zone. Also, keep in mind that many math concepts require some time to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

As you approach $x$, the limit is $0$, for any $x$. It doesn't matter whether or not $x$ is an integer because a limit does not care about the value at $x$, it cares about what happens as you approach $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In intuitive terms, the limit at a point is *the same value as that at the close neighbors* *.

For the given $f$, whatever the $x$, integer or not, the value at the close neighbors is $0$ (if the chosen neighborhood contains an integer, you can take a smaller neighborhood).

More specifically,

- if $x$ is an integer, $f=0$ over $(x-1,x+1)$;
- if $x$ is a non-integer, $f=0$ over $(\lfloor x\rfloor,\lceil x\rceil)$.

The value of $f$ at $x$ itself is *not* taken into account.

---

*Mind the oversimplification. Usually the values in the neighborhood aren't equal. So the true definition of a limit works with the idea that you can find a neighborhood where the values are as close as you want from each other, i.e. the variations are bounded by an arbitrary tolerance.